# if statement inside gridview ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have Gridview Item template where I need to add a condition.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opened Date">

                <ItemTemplate>

                    <%#Eval("OpenedDate")%>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I need to add a condition to run the  <%#Eval("OpenedDate")%> only when the value from another template value is equals to "yes"

```
<%#Place.GetColoredGetYESNOfromBOOL1(Eval("OpenHouse").ToString())%>
```

I am working on the below code, but I am getting syntax error.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opened Date">

                    <ItemTemplate>
<% if (%>
<%#Place.GetColoredGetYESNOfromBOOL1(Eval("OpenHouse").ToString())=="yes" )%>

                        <%#Eval("OpenedDate")%>
                       <% ) %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676803/can-i-use-an-if-statement-in-a-gridview-itemtemplate

Comment: You can't put a databinding block in the middle of an if statement. Put your conditional code in the code behind in the ItemDataBound event or similar. not in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put if statement in the Item Template instead you can check and put your code after the row is bounded to the gridview

Try this code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     //here you put the if statement to get the "OpenHouse" column value
     if(e.Row.Cells[Column Index].Text.Equals("Yes")){
         //your code here
     }
}
```

Comment: i updated the code behind as above, but it is reading "" for every cell                           if(e.Row.Cells[5].Text.Equals("Yes")){
        e.Row.Cells[6].Text.Equals("")
     }

Comment: if you want to set new value to Row.Cells[6]
try this:

e.Row.Cells[6].Text="new value"

Comment: i can get it to set new value, but the problem I am having is that to put a condition (if the value on e.Row.Cells[5] equals to ("some text") then set new value on e.Row.Cells[6].Text="blank"). For some reason any condition I put comes back with null (does not see it).

Comment: in the Item template add label and give it id "Mylabel"
then in the code try this:
Label Mylabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Mylabel");
            if (e.Row.Cells[5].Text.Equals("somtext"))
            {
                Mylabel.Text = "new value";
            }